# Can "Current Mohan" conduct high levels of electrical current through his body?

Tags: physiology, electromagnetism

I saw this episode of *[Stan Lee's Superhumans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee%27s_Superhumans)* featuring Raj Mohan Nair, also known as "Current Mohan". He seems to be able to conduct electric current through his body to power up household electrical appliances without suffering the adverse effects of electric shock and electrocution.

[ParaSci reports](http://parasci.net/1164):

> Raj Mohan Nair, or Current Mohan as he calls himself, possesses the unlikely ability to withstand large amounts of electrical current. To put it simply, he can’t be electrocuted. Mohan first discovered his gift after his mother’s passing at the age of seven. Feeling suicidal, he climbed a nearby transformer and grabbed hold of a wire. Miraculously, Mohan withstood a typically fatal amount of electrical current, making him aware of his unique physiological capabilities. Current Mohan was born.

The report includes a History channel documentary about him. He also appears in this [video](http://youtu.be/PRf9MqqkMDM) performing various stunts.

Is this for real?